# Travelling to Greece without knowing the language

Tags: greece, language-barrier

I am considering travelling to Greece to compete in the Athens Classic Marathon, but I do not speak any Greek.

I will be fine once I get to the hotel as the travel provider will be onsite and transfers to the start are included, and the hotel is within walking distance of the finish line. But I am concerned about getting through customs and getting to and from the airport to the hotel.

Will I have issues in customs, or are there English speaking staff available?

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Languages_of_Greece, English is one of the four foreign languages most commonly studied in Greece. And this one https://www.tripsavvy.com/essential-things-to-know-about-greece-1526338  mentions that all school children start learning English in 3rd grade. You’ll have no problems.

Comment: The only ***essential*** thing you need to know about Greek is that the word for "yes" sounds something like the English word "no", and the word for "no" sounds something like the English "O.K."

Comment: I did it, no problems. don't worry, english and a smile is good enough.

Comment: I mean imagine if this was a problem.

Comment: I speak a little Greek, but in my experience Greeks were extremely surprised and pleased to encounter a foreigner who spoke any Greek beyond basic greetings. To them, it was a complete anomaly. If you're only going to be in Athens, I wouldn't worry at all. If you were going to be out in rural areas, you might run into more situations where lack of language might be more of a problem. It won't hurt to learn how to say hello=yah sas, and thank you=efharisto, with the stress on the final syllable.

Comment: I was there 2 months ago, don't speak any Greek and had zero problems. You'll be fine :)

Comment: Talking to people is no problem - English of minimal proficiency is nearly ubiquitous.  Taking a bus is harder: You have to be able to read the Greek alphabet and map what you see to the place you want to go before it goes whizzing past ...

Comment: I'm Greek and I can tell you that almost everybody (and certainly *all* young people) speak English. It's like a second nature. Don't forget that most TV movies and serials are not dubbed so people grow up listening to English. And 99% of young people learn English as a foreign language (many also learn French and/or German). Being a polyglott is the most normal situation (it's a Greek word in the first place).

Comment: One issue would be if you have a food allegry, and more specificly a allegy to sea food.  Many Greek resturants do not have staff that speaks english and I was not always sure about what I was ordering (I enjoyed that tbh).  The tourist area around the Acropolis you will find service in english.

Comment: @Traveller Well … all Japanese children study English at school and yet good luck getting by in Japan on English only.

Comment: @Jan I agree. My comment was not intended to imply English should somehow be spoken and understood by all, and it cited independent sources rather than just my opinion. Not sure how your comment is relevant to a question about Greece.

Comment: @Traveller I was pointing out that just because many people study a language doesn’t mean that you can get by with that language. So while your sources are probably accurate, they don’t say anything about what it’s like in the streets. I provided the counterexample to prove that A is not a prerequisite for B.

Comment: @Jan Every answer to this question, including one from a native of Greece living there, states the OP will not have any problems (on the street or elsewhere), especially given that their destination is Athens rather than a more remote mainland area or island.

Comment: @Traveller And that is fine. Your comment implies that: English at school => speaking English is fine. That conclusion is not valid. That’s the only point I contest.

Comment: @davidbak A trick is to figure out where you want to get off beforehand and then check your progress with google maps (preferably get offline maps beforehand although if you have a European SIM roaming is fine these days). That or get really good at pattern recognition quickly. Since I failed at the latter, I stuck with the former when taking busses in say China ;)

Comment: @davidbak And learning the alphabet is pretty easy too, to be honest, at least well enough to read signs. It’s 24 letters, of which at least a good half are immediately recognisable, just variants on the same as their Latin counterparts (you don’t have to be a genius to guess which brands of science ΖΟΟΛΟΓΙΑ or ΒΙΟΛΟΓΙΑ are, for example). If you set your mind to it, you can learn to read Greek quite usably in a day.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - my experience in Athens - many many years ago - was that the buses went by too fast, their stops were very short.  Once you could read the sign they were gone before you could decide it was your bus or not.  But as Voo above points out - today we have Google Maps! So I suppose they have live bus updates too.

Comment: As others have said, you'll have no problems at all, but anyway, make sure to use Google Translate since it really helps with real time translation. I remember last summer I was in Indonesia and it really helped my with the local people.

Comment: Most European countries, including Greece, are OK to visit if you only speak English.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You'll manage. I speak from recent experience: I completed last year's Athens Classic Marathon (which incidentally led to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/162631/22219), but I digress). Unlike you I didn't book via a travel provider but arranged everything myself; I've visited a couple of restaurants outside the city center and all waiters spoke decent English. I haven't spoken more than a handful of words in Greek (more or less the list in [@Graham's answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/154533/28333)). To clarify: that wouldn't have been necessary, but to me personally it adds to my holiday experience and it's a (very minor) sign of respect/appreciation.

Public transport (including the subway that connects the airport to the city center) has all its stations published in both the Greek and the Latin alphabet, so you don't even need to learn 24 new letters. The announcements in the subway are in Greek, then in English.

Enjoy the marathon (pro tip: the last 11 km are downhill and *really* easy compared to other marathons), and don't forget to enjoy Athens itself as well; the marathon is during low season, so most tourist attractions are half price and less than half as busy as otherwise. And the weather is still quite nice (compared to where I live, at least).

Answer (score 48):

Millions of people per year visit Greece, and I'm willing to bet that a large portion of them do not speak any Greek. It's a very popular holiday destination for English speaking people. I can't imagine you would have much trouble at all<sup>1</sup>.

Immigration and customs should be no problem. Have the name of your hotel written down in the unlikely event you get a taxi driver who can't understand where you want to go.

<sub>1. Source: My wife visited Greece for a month many years ago without knowing a single word of Greek beforehand.</sub>

Comment: Or use Uber and you won't have even that issue.  (On my last visit to Greece, admittedly 10+ years ago, the average cabbie did *not* speak much English at all.)

Comment: Uber in Athens is different from regular Uber. It's uber taxi. You use the uber app but a regular cab is called. Beware of this and follow greg advice and carry the name and street of your hotel and destinations written down. I had an issue in Athens as the cab driver didn't speak an ounce of English.

Comment: You may also find the place of your hotel on Google maps and just show it to the taxi driver.

Comment: @Michael Based on personal experience, I'd be a bit wary of using Google Maps for getting around Athens. It's not bad as long as you stick to main streets, but there are numerous places throughout the city that the map data Google has is somewhat dated. Last trip I took, it took me far longer than it should have the first night to get back to my hotel because Google maps was missing a number of side streets and trying to route me through a brick wall.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn The suggestion was not to use gmap to find a route, but to show the taxi-driver where you want to end up.  *They* will then do the route finding.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica I understand that, but given the issues I've seen with the map data, I wouldn't want to count on it to even show the correct address for a given location in some parts of the city.

Answer (score 22):

> am concerned about getting through customs and getting to and from the airport to the hotel. Will i have issues in customs, or are there english speaking staff available?

Living in Greece all my life I can assure you that, nope, you won't.

As a famous tourist destination almost all tourist related jobs here require some sort of proficiency in speaking English. In places like customs I believe you'd be hard pressed to find someone who *doesn't speak* English.

Taxis might be more of a mixed bag but the metro is always an available and less expensive option with employees that are, again, required to be able to speak english.

Finally, you can always ask around if you need anything, the younger the person, the more likely they speak English.

---

Note, of course, all this applies to Athens. The further you get from any city the less likely you are to encounter people who will understand English.

Comment: So a three month old is more likely to speak English than a three year old?

Comment: @phoog Well, the gap between their Greek and English ability will be less.  More seriously, I think that the intended meaning is obvious.

Answer (score 17):

You should not have problems.

My recent experience in Greece (mainly in Crete, off-season):

- Athens airport: no problem, English is understood, signs are also in English, personnel speak English. There is no problem in customs (like most countries: it is not necessary to know local language).
- Car rental: no problem: you will have documents in English, and people will speak at minimum basic English (with accent)
- Taxi: no problem, but better to have the address written down (Latin characters are fine)
- Restaurants: In a small one, they will find a way to communicate with you, usually using a son/daughter, or asking an local guest to help. They also have tourist menus (with images) or they show you what they can provide.
- Tourist attraction: signs, entries, prices are displayed also in English (Euro currency), most people know enough English.

Most directions on streets are also in English.

You may want to learn Greek alphabet, but not necessary. You may not be able to read all signs (e.g. pharmacy, but logo will help).

You may lose some local chatting (because you do not know Greek, and locals will often not go much further than basic English), but this may not be a problem.

You may try also with Italian, German, French, or Spanish, especially with older people.

Note: I recommend Google Translator (with offline dictionary) on phone, just if you are curious about meaning of some words, and on restaurants ask for a WiFi: the English name of Greek specialties may not say much for us, but Google Image Search helps.

Comment: The only trouble I had in 10 days in greece was a small fast food gyro place. They didn't want to slow down their insanely fast gyro-making to try to communicate with my english-only self. Even so, I did eventually get my gyros.

Comment: The *"In a small one, they will find a way to communicate with you, usually using a son/daughter, or asking an local guest to help"* is so true in Greece (and many southern countries). The smaller the restaurant, the more probable. I had guests jumping in uninvited to help; One (in Italy) even **forced** me to taste his meal so I know what I am ordering. Fantastic experiences.

Answer (score 12):

A phrasebook will certainly help.  So will "nee", "oki", "yassas", "efharisto" and "parakello" ("yes", "no", "hallo", "thank you", and either "please" or "you're welcome").  Whilst you can certainly expect most Greeks to speak English to a greater or lesser extent, it is profoundly rude to rock up in someone else's country without knowing even those basics.  You'll get a much better response if you can at least say "yassas" in greeting before you ask "Do you speak English?"

That said, you should be fine with just English, especially in Athens.

Further afield, as with many places in the Mediterranean, it's very common to find German spoken as the dominant "tourist" language and fewer people speaking English.  In Athens though you should be fine.

Answer (score 7):

I have visited Athens twice on business.  At the airport, everyone I dealt with spoke English reasonably enough. I had no problems at passport control, customs, etc. I had no problem getting a taxi and communicating with the driver - although I always carried with me a piece of paper with the address of the hotel.

Once in the city, again, I had no problem with transportation or restaurants - most restaurants either had a menu in English or someone who spoke reasonable English.

In short, no problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer, but may be relevant:

In the days of phrasebooks, when somewhere really exotic and non-English, I would point to the phrase in the book, which also made for a lot of entertainment on all sides. These days you can do that with Google translate, then you all gather around and have a smile.

Answer (score 1):

Took a holiday in Athens. The language was all Greek to me.

Had no issues being understood or understanding. Most restaurant menus are double language and there are many people who can speak English. If you go away from the touristy areas, you may find it is less easy to get by. But as long as you can get back to where you started, you're not going to starve.

Even on the subway/underground, the signs are clear and it is very easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, English is widely spoken in Greece and many people are bilingual. You'll find that the majority of signs, menus and other written materials in tourist areas are usually translated into English. However, it's recommended to learn a few key phrases in Greek before travelling - this will be greatly appreciated by locals who may not necessarily speak English fluently, and it will help make your journey more enjoyable.

**Tourist Dictionaries**
There are a variety of resources available to help you learn basic Greek phrases, such as an online course or language learning app, or physical books and CDs. Additionally, many tourist areas offer pocket-sized translation dictionaries to visitors. Knowing a few words in the local language can be invaluable when asking for directions, ordering food or drinks in a restaurant, and engaging with locals. It's also polite to know the basic customs and traditions of the country you're visiting - for example, Greeks generally greet each other with two kisses on either cheek. Taking some time to familiarise yourself with these cultural nuances will help you have an authentic and enjoyable experience during your travels.

**Use Language Learning Application**
There are also a number of language learning applications available, such as [Duolingo](https://twitter.com/duolingo) and Babbel, that allow you to learn Greek phrases on the go. These apps usually come with interactive lessons and audio clips so you can practice your pronunciation, as well as games and quizzes to test your knowledge. They're great for brushing up on your language skills on the go, and you can even download the lessons for offline use so you don't need to worry about staying connected to WiFi.

Finally, it's important to remember that the Greek people are very friendly and accommodating, so don't be afraid to ask for help if you get stuck. With a little bit of preparation, travelling in Greece without knowing the language will be a breeze!

Comment: This is a very nicely written piece. Question: are you affiliated with Duolingo? You posted a link to their Twitter but not to the Twitter of Babbel (if they have any) The system thinks this is spam (advertisement for Duolingo) for that reason (I think)

Answer (score 0):

I've been to Greece a few times.

Not all Greeks are super good in English but for the most of time in doesn't matter as gestures etc is understood - but you should always be friendly and take your time communicating.

If you're a citizen of the EU then you will have free roaming in Greece and you can then use Google Translate to make communication easier. If your phone provider doesn't provide free or cheap roaming in Greece then you might want to consider getting a Greek SIM card ASAP so that you can do translations and also use online maps.